# Convergence and sum of geometric series $(e^{3-2n})$ as $n$ goes from $2$ to $\infty$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have simplified the expression to:

(e^3 / e^2n)

This particular question asks to answer whether or not the series converges by virtue of **|common ratio| < 1** alone, without using any other tests (besides checking if the limit DNE or does not equal 0), and then to find the sum using the formula **first term/(1-r)**.

The limit appears to go to 0, so the series does not diverge.  As I cannot fit the the expression in the form **a(r)^(n)**, I'm currently unable to either say whether or not the series converges and what the sum is.

I just need help manipulating the expression to the form **a(r)^(n)**, then I can answer the rest.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{3-2n}= e^3 +e +\sum_{n=2}^{n=\infty} e^{3-2n}= e^3\cdot \frac {1}{1-\frac {1}{e^2}}$$ and this because $e^{-2}<1$ ,thus $$\sum_{n=2}^{n=\infty} e^{3-2n}=e^3\cdot \frac {1}{1-\frac {1}{e^2}}-e^3-e$$